# How should I protect a gas line in a closet?

Tags: pipe, code-compliance, natural-gas

What is the best way to protect and hide a gas line that runs along the side wall of an open (no door) closet? It sits about 2” off the ground and is 1” away from the wall. Since it’s an open closet I would like to build something that looks nice around it, however, I don’t know if there are any codes that I would be violating by doing this. The gas line runs the length of the closet which is 10’.

[image]

Comment: How high up the wall does the vertical section run?  Is there shelving on either wall that might influence the answer?

Comment: It goes up about 2 - 3 feet. I was planning on putting shelving on that wall and the opposite wall (not visible in the photo). So at this point the room is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically would build a bulkhead to contain this.  Any enclosed gas pipe/water/electric should be built with a wall that meets code

This means the bulkhead should be framed out like a mini wall.  Floor plate, top plate, wall plate, joists and studs 16" O/C.  Frame it out affixed firmly to the wall (anchoring the wall plate in the studs) and glue down or preferably anchor down the floor plate.  Angle it to go all the way up the wall to enclose the vertical portion of the pipe.

Once you frame it all in, cover in sheet rock, mud and tape.  And paint.

Then you can finish it out and use the bulkhead (excluding the vertical part) to make a cool shoe shelf.

Comment: Can you use 2x2's for this instead of 2x4's since it isn't structural?

Comment: Can you?  Yes.  Should you?  ... I certainly wouldn't.  It's gonna be in a closet, which means it'll get used as storage, which means it should be as sturdy as any other wall.  And it's got a gas pipe running in it.